# How do I make add_image_size thumbnails percentages in php?

Tags: php, resize, width

In my theme-functions.php file, I have

```
add_image_size('ad-medium', $width = 250, $height = 250, true );
```

This determines the size that Wordpress creates 'ad-medium' thumbnails. Any changes to this code determine what is shown on the website instantly.

So if I change the 250 to 100, the width will be reduced to 100px. Unfortunately, this has three problems:

1. This changes the dimensions of all future upload resizing for ad-medium, so that's out of the question.
2. The height is ignored - I can't warp it - it stays 1:1 aspect ratio no matter what.
3. I can't write 100%. The percentage sign is not understood.

In context, the code is:

```
    <?php
}


// activate theme support items
if (function_exists('add_theme_support')) { // added in 2.9

    // this theme uses post thumbnails
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails', array('post', 'page'));
    set_post_thumbnail_size(100, 100); // normal post thumbnails

    // add default posts and comments RSS feed links to head
    add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );
}

// setup different image sizes
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
    add_image_size('blog-thumbnail', 150, 150); // blog post thumbnail size, box crop mode
    add_image_size('sidebar-thumbnail', 140, 140, true); // sidebar blog thumbnail size, box crop mode

    // create special sizes for the ads
    add_image_size('ad-thumb', 75, 75, true); 
    add_image_size('ad-small', 100, 100, true);
    add_image_size('ad-medium', $width = 250, $height = 250, true );
    //add_image_size('ad-large', 500, 500); 
}

// Set the content width based on the theme's design and stylesheet.
// Used to set the width of images and content. Should be equal to the width the theme
// is designed for, generally via the style.css stylesheet.
if (!isset($content_width))
    $content_width = 500;


// This theme supports native menu options, and uses wp_nav_menu() in one location for top navigation.
function appthemes_register_menus() {
    register_nav_menus(array(
        'primary' => __( 'Primary Navigation', 'appthemes' ),
        'secondary' => __( 'Footer Navigation', 'appthemes' ),
        'theme_dashboard' => __( 'Theme Dashboard', 'appthemes' )
    ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'appthemes_register_menus' );

//ajax header javascript builder for child categories AJAX dropdown builder
function cp_ajax_addnew_js_header() {
    global $app_abbr;
    $parentPosting = get_option($app_abbr.'_ad_parent_posting');
    // Define custom JavaScript function
?>
```

How can I leave the thumbnail resizing feature alone and add another line of code that will resize it to 100% width 100% height? At the moment, the whole page is resizing except the stubborn thumbnails.

Please let me know what to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails: Post Thumbnails are given a class "wp-post-image". They also get a class depending on the size of the thumbnail being displayed You can style the output with these CSS selectors.

So you can add to your theme css file:

```
 #content img.ad-medium {height:100%; Width:100%;}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I ended up having to edit the wp-includes/media.php file. This is a root wordpress file:

Comment: $default_attr = array(
   'src' => $src,
   'class' => "attachment-$size",
   'alt' => trim(strip_tags( get_post_meta($attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true) )), // Use Alt field first,
   'style'=> "width:100%;max-width:100%;height: auto;" //added this line
  );
  if ( empty($default_attr['alt']) )
   $default_attr['alt'] = trim(strip_tags( $attachment->post_excerpt )); // If not, Use the Caption
  if ( empty($default_attr['alt']) )
   $default_attr['alt'] = trim(strip_tags( $attachment->post_title )); // Finally, use the title